Next Js - Component must rebuild to update after item add to database
i have big problem
my project have website and admin panel , in run dev works perfect like add category in admin panel immidietly but when run next buil and start . after add item in example add category , item added succesfully to database but not show in website
i must have stop and re build project to change applied
where is my problem ?
